# Allow traffic to/from specific IP with iptables in openwrt

Tags: iptables, openwrt

I have a tp-link router with openwrt. I have 2 iptables rules to block P2P connections. The blockings working fine, but now I need a rule to allow traffic to/from a specific IP.

my blocking rules:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --string "BitTorrent protocol" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --string ".torrent" --algo bm -j DROP
```

I add this rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.64.XX -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.64.XX -j ACCEPT
```

but doesn't work.

I tried with little modifications:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.64.XX -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.64.XX -j ACCEPT
```

Still doesn't work. I restarted the router after every rule change.

Now I can't see my modifications in the firewall, I only see this:

```
Chain FORWARD (Policy: DROP, Packets: 0, Traffic: 0.00 B)
Rule #  Pkts.   Traffic Target  Prot.   Flags   In  Out Source  Destination Options
1   0   0.00 B  DROP    all --  *   *   0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   STRING match ".torrent" ALGO name bm TO 65535
2   96  10.39 KB    DROP    all --  *   *   0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   STRING match "BitTorrent protocol" ALGO name bm TO 65535
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rules added by hand with `iptables` do not survive a reboot, unless the init system takes care of saving and restoring them between boots. I don't think openwrt does that in its default configuration.

Look for another place to add custom firewall rules. Maybe `/etc/config/firewall` ?

Details on the configuration format are here:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall

Comment: Lol, my bad, i type the rule command with L, but that's an I :D Now i restarted the firewall with /etc/init.d/firewall restart and working fine ;)